# Use regex to match lines with character repeated exactly n times

Tags: grep

I am looking for a regular expression of grep that matches exactly the string **rr** in a line.
An example of data file is:

```
rr                     
q  rrr a                 
  abcrr d                
rarrrrrr aaa rrqq   
kdhdrraa  rrzaza
```

And the expected result:

```
rr
  abcrr d
rarrrrrr aaa rrqq
kdhdrraa rrzaza
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

With standard `grep` syntax and BRE:

```
$ grep -x '\(.*[^r]\)\{0,1\}rr\([^r].*\)\{0,1\}' < file
rr
abcrr d
rarrrrrr aaa rrqq
kdhdrraa rrzaza
```

<sup>(replace `rr` with `r\{42\}` for 42 `r`s)</sup>

That is match e**x**actly  (that is the whole line) on `rr` optionally (`\{0,1\}` being 0 or 1, equivalent of ERE `?`) preceded by a sequence of characters that ends in a character  other than `r` (`[^r]`) and optionally followed by a sequence of characters starting with a character other than `r`.

With ERE:

```
$ grep -E '(^|[^r])rr([^r]|$)' < file
rr
abcrr d
rarrrrrr aaa rrqq
kdhdrraa rrzaza
```

<sup>(replace `rr` with `r{42}` for 42 `r`s)</sup>

That is `rr` preceded by either the start of the line or a character other than `r` and followed by either the end of the line or a character other than `r`.

With PCRE (non-standard):

```
$ grep -P '(?<!r)rr(?!r)' < file
rr
abcrr d
rarrrrrr aaa rrqq
kdhdrraa rrzaza
```

<sup>(replace `rr` with `r{42}` for 42 `r`s)</sup>

That is, `rr` **not** preceded nor followed by `r`.

With *Augmented* RE (ast-open `grep`):

```
$ grep -xX '(.*r)!rr(r.*)!' < file
rr
abcrr d
rarrrrrr aaa rrqq
kdhdrraa rrzaza
```

<sup>(replace `rr` with `r{42}` for 42 `r`s)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very mutch.with my version  of grep, grep -E '(^|[^r])rr([^r]|$)' and

Comment: grep -P '(?<!r)rr(?!r)' work very well.