# grep - regex that will find exactly 3 a's in a string

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

I'd like to alter the following command so that the regex matches words in /usr/share/dict/words that contain *exactly* 3 a's instead of *at least* 3 a's.

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words | grep "a.*a.*a" | grep -v "'s$" | wc -l
```

How do I do this?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403721/117549 seems helpful

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's one way with `[^a]` (match any character other than `a`) instead of `.` (match any character):

```
$ grep -E '^([^a]*a){3}[^a]*$' /usr/share/dict/cracklib-small | shuf -n 4
areaway
humanitarian
capitalizations
autonavigator
```

You can also write the regexp like `^[^a]*(a[^a]*){3}$` with the same results.

It's also equivalent to `^[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*$` which doesn't scale when you want a different number of a's. Performance is much better though, not that it matters unless you're grepping through gigabytes of data.

Instead of explicitly using the `^` and `$` regexp anchor operators, you can also use the `-x` option which does that implicitly. See also the `-i` option to match case insensitively (according to locale):

```
grep -xiE '([^a]*a){3}[^a]*'
```

Comment: Instead of a capturing group (`( ... )`), you can use the non-capturing group (`(?: ... )`), which should be faster (specially for large inputs).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, `(?:...)` is a perl regexp operator. Few `grep` implementations support it in their `-E` regexps.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Makes sense. On my quick Google search I didn't find anything about that.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, ast-open's `grep` (not widely used) is the only one I know that supports `(?:..)` in their EREs. Several `grep` implementations (including GNU `grep` when built with *"experimental"* PCRE support) support a `-P` to use perl-like regexps.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The difference between capturing and non-capturing groups is negligible in `grep`, since it doesn't do anything with the groups.

Answer (score 14):

Use the same sort of pattern to detect "at least 4 `a`s", and invert the sense of the match:

```
grep 'a.*a.*a' /usr/share/dict/words | grep -v 'a.*a.*a.*a'
```

or,

```
grep '\(a.*\)\{3\}' /usr/share/dict/words | grep -v '\(a.*\)\{4\}'
```

or,

```
grep -E '(a.*){3}' /usr/share/dict/words | grep -v -E '(a.*){4}'
```

---

Alternatively, use `awk` with `a` as the field delimiter and count the fields:

```
awk -F a 'NF == 4' /usr/share/dict/words
```

(on lines with three `a`s, there would be four fields)

---

Alternatively, use Perl's `tr` operator to count the number of `a`s on each line:

```
perl -ne 'print if (tr/a/a/ == 3)' /usr/share/dict/words
```

The operator returns the number of transliterations made, and we're replacing each `a` with another `a`, so the actual output would not be modified.